# How can I figure out the average consecutive duration of "True" values in pandas df, per group?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, datetime

With the following data, I think I want a column (`DESIRED_DURATION_COL`) to work out the duration (according to `start_datetime`) of consecutive Truths:

| project_id | start_datetime | diag_local_code | DESIRED_DURATION_COL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-01-18 | False | 0 |
| 1 | 2019-04-14 | True | 0 |
| 1 | 2019-04-17 | True | 3 |
| 1 | 2019-04-19 | False | 0 |
| 1 | 2019-04-23 | True | 0 |
| 1 | 2019-04-25 | True | 2 |
| 1 | 2019-04-30 | True | 7 |
| 1 | 2019-05-21 | False | 0 |

This is so I can get the average truth duration (mean), per `project_id`, such that I get a df like:

| project_id | avg_duration |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 2 |

Can't work out how to do this, thanks in advance!

Comment: How `5` of column `avg_duration` is calculated in your second table?

Comment: The average of total duration for each discrete group of cumulative Truths : (3 + 7) / 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for calculating `duration`:

```
m = df['diag_local_code']
dt = df[m].groupby(['project_id', (~m).cumsum()])['start_datetime'].transform('first')
df['duration'] = df['start_datetime'].sub(dt).dt.days.fillna(0)
```

How this works?

Use `cumsum` on inverted `diag_local_code` to identify groups of consecutive ones per `project_id`, then filter the rows where `diag_local_code` is `True` then group the filtered dataframe and transform `start_datetime` with `first` to broadcast first date value across each group, finally subtract the broadcasted date value from `start_datetime` to calculate the desired duration

Result

```
   project_id start_datetime  diag_local_code  duration
0           1     2017-01-18            False       0.0
1           1     2019-04-14             True       0.0
2           1     2019-04-17             True       3.0
3           1     2019-04-19            False       0.0
4           1     2019-04-23             True       0.0
5           1     2019-04-25             True       2.0
6           1     2019-04-30             True       7.0
7           1     2019-05-21            False       0.0
```

---

Solution for calculating average consecutive duration of `True` values

```
m = df['diag_local_code']
(
    df[m].groupby(['project_id', (~m).cumsum()])['start_datetime']
         .agg(np.ptp).dt.days.groupby(level=0).mean().reset_index(name='avg_duration')
)
```

Result:

```
   project_id  avg_duration
0           1           5.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this! How can I now calculate the average duration? (i.e. just the mean of 3 and 7?)

Comment: @chillingfox Can you explain the logic/formula to calculate the average? Do you need to discard the zeros while calculating mean?

Comment: For each project_id, I want to find the mean duration of Truths. So for `project_id = 1`, I want to find the mean of the total duration of each discrete group of consecutive truths i.e. 3 and 7. So would be discarding 0's and any value that isn't the max cumulative duration

Comment: @chillingfox Is the dataframe sorted on start date?

Comment: Yep it is, and on project_id

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `project_id` column and split each group into consecutive value groups. Then check the groups value is all `True`.

```py
def avg_duration(group):
    subgroup = group.groupby(group['diag_local_code'].diff().ne(0).cumsum())
    true_count = subgroup.apply(lambda g: g['diag_local_code'].all()).sum()
    true_last_sum = subgroup.apply(lambda g: g.iloc[-1]['DESIRED_DURATION_COL'] if g['diag_local_code'].all() else 0).sum()
    return true_last_sum/true_count

out = df.groupby('project_id').apply(avg_duration).to_frame('avg_duration').reset_index()
```

```
print(out)

   project_id  avg_duration
0           1           5.0
```